# How to listen to keyUp event in capture mode?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I am looking at Dart API to find a way to listen to KeyUp event using capture mode. But with this new stream system there's no parameter to specify capture anymore:

```dart
document.body.onKeyUp.listen(callback); // where's the old "useCapture" parameter?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve the same thing with Streams, here's an example:

```dart
Element.keyUpEvent.forTarget(document.body, useCapture: true).listen((e) {
  // Do your stuff.
  print('Here we go');
});
```

The method we used above, creates a stream for you with capture mode. The Stream interface (`listen()` method) is quite generic, and thus can't have this specific functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method:

```dart
GlobalEventHandlers.clickEvent.forTarget(dom.document, useCapture: true).listen((e) {
  // Do your stuff.
});
```